# jq command to convert epoch time

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, datetime-format

I run the following AWS command using the `jq`, but it returns the time in epoch.

```
# aws ecs describe-tasks \
    --tasks arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:87147902d5269:task/ABC/1a9a276e0a0443d3d37ff954cfa6b1f36bc66 \
    --cluster arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:87147902d5269:cluster/CDE \
    | jq -r '.tasks[]|.taskArn,.createdAt,.taskDefinitionArn'
```

```
arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:871479025269:task/ABC/1a9a276e0a044d3d337ff954cfa6b1f36bc66
1595602422.013
arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:87147922025269:task-definition/new:1
```

How can I convert the epoch time into a date within the same command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `todateiso8601` to convert the epoch time to an iso date string.

```
$ <<< '1595602422.013' jq 'todateiso8601'
"2020-07-24T14:53:42Z"
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/lV7QRakEAI)

```
$ ... | jq -r '.tasks[] | .taskArn, (.createdAt | todateiso8601), .taskDefinitionArn'
arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:871479025269:task/ABC/1a9a276e0a044d3d337ff954cfa6b1f36bc66
2020-07-24T14:53:42Z
arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:87147922025269:task-definition/new:1
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/silDOj_whG)